# Calculating work done by f x = (x,x)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, asymptotic-complexity

Let's say I have this function: (Haskell syntax)

```
f x = (x,x)
```

What is the work (amount of calculation) performed by the function?

At first I thought it was obviously constant, but what if the type of `x` is not finite, meaning, x can take an arbitrary amount of memory? One would have to take into account the work done by copying `x` as well, right?

This led me to believe that the work done by the function is actually linear in the size of the input.

This isn't homework for itself, but came up when I had to define the work done by the function:

```
f x = [x]
```

Which has a similar issue, I believe.

Comment: good question for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should I move it? (Assuming I can, I'm not really familiar with the site)

Comment: @Guido You can't move it, although it's not possible to move it to the destination I think it fits, too. IMHO it's best to leave it here.

Comment: Note that an expression like `(x,x)` could trigger evaluation of `x` twice depending on whether the monomorphism restriction is in effect or not. E.g. see this recent blog post: [http://ics.p.lodz.pl/~stolarek/blog/2012/05/towards-understanding-haskells-monomorphism-restriction/](Towards understanding Haskell’s monomorphism restriction)

Comment: @Guido Are you Guido Van Rossum?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Very informally, the work done depends on your language's operational semantics. Haskell, well, it's lazy, so you pay only constant factors to:

- push pointers to `x` on the stack
- allocate a heap cell for `(,)`
- apply `(,)` to its arguments
- return a pointer to the heap cell

Done. *O(1)* work, performed when the caller looks at the result of `f`.

Now, you will trigger further evaluation if you look inside the `(,)` -- and that work is dependent on the work to evaluate `x` itself. Since in Haskell the references to `x` are shared, you evaluate it only once.

So the work in Haskell is *O(work of x)* if you fully evaluate the result. Your function `f` only adds constant factors.

Comment: To further clarify: `(,)` in Haskell is a *boxed* tuple, which means that it is a construct that merely holds pointers. If you have a language where `(,)` creates an *unboxed* tuple, then yes, it will take extra work to clone `x` to both slots, if `x` is larger than a pointer, and the amount of work scales with the size of `x`. [GHC provides unboxed tuples](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/primitives.html#unboxed-tuples) `(#,#)` with various limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Okasaki has a wonderful method of determining the work charged to function call when some (or total) laziness is introduced.  I believe it is in his paper on Purely Functional Data Structures.  I know it is in the book version -- I read that part of the book last month.  Basically you charge a constant factor for the promise/thunk created, charge nothing for evaluating any passed in promises/thunks (assume they've already been forced / are in normal form [not just WHNF]).  That's an underestimate.  If you want an overestimate charge also the cost of forcing / converting to normal form each promise / thunk created by the function.  At least, that's how I remember it in my extremely tired state.

Look it up in Okasaki: http://www.westpoint.edu/eecs/SitePages/Chris%20Okasaki.aspx#thesis -- I swear the thesis used be be downloadable.

Comment: In Haskell having a polymorphic argument would seem to invalidate Okasaki's method.  (1) Avoid if possible.  (2) I haven't fully analyzed this, it's just an intuition.